# encoding unsigned int

Tags: java, c++

I have the following code in java that I need to convert to c++ to be able to encode unsigned int.

```
public static int enc_uint32be( int i, byte[] dst, int di ) {
        dst[di++] = (byte)((i >> 24) & 0xFF);
        dst[di++] = (byte)((i >> 16) & 0xFF);
        dst[di++] = (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xFF);
        dst[di] = (byte)(i & 0xFF);
        return 4;
}
```

I am a newbie to java. I trust several experts on this forum know both languages - can someone help me with the translation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the data type that you are planning on using, but if you just change:

```
 byte[] dst
```

to

```
unsigned char dst[]
```

in the function declaration, then it should behave the same (and change the byte usages in the function to `unsigned char` as well).

Comment: thanks, this is for stock prices so I believe char should work. I am sure I will have more questions as I try to convert more of the code.

Comment: You might be interested in `typedef unsigned char byte;`, which would ease some of the conversion slightly.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the code in Java is almost the same in C++ with small modifications:

- byte is not a valid type in C++, the equivalent is unsigned char
- The array parameter type must be reworked as @MarkWilkins mentionned.

Comment: thanks..I am sure I will post more questions on the conversion